# sms_autofill flutter package - SmsAutoFill.getAppSignature getter return null in all cases

Tags: flutter, mobile

I am trying to implement autofill sms OTP code in flutter application. I installed: https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill/example (sms_autofill package), but when I try to use getter from that library for getting signature with: SmsAutoFill.getAppSignature, it returns me null all the time. I saw that it is returning normal value on the older examples on the internet and I saw that package updated 27 days ago, so I am not sure it that update affected that package is not working anymore.

I also made new flutter app and copied code from package example and their example is also returning null.

Comment: SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature ****

Comment: Share code segment for better understanding of your problem